# Typescript: Applying generic type class to all types in list

Tags: typescript, observable, httpresponse, generic-programming

How can I create from a list of types `[T1, T2, T3, ...]` a list of for example `[Array<T1>, Array<T2>, Array<T3>, ...]`?

Use case: I want to define a generic type class of the following structure:

```
class BaseService<T> {
  abstract getObservable(): Observable<HttpResponse<T>>;
  abstract func(responses: T): void;
  
  getData() {
    this.getObservable().subscribe(
      (http_response) => this.func(http_response.body)
    );
  }
}
```

where `getObservable()` and `func(...)` are defined in the class extending this one. Problem is I have a varying amount of observables, T1, T2, etc. I tried using `base = new BaseService<[T1, T2]>()` but then the `getObservable()` function should return the type `Observable<[HttpResponse<T1>, HttpResponse<T2>]>` and not `Observable<HttpResponse<[T1, T2]>>` (hence the initial question). I also tried using `base = new BaseService<T1, T2>()`  by redefining the class to

```
class BaseService<T1, T2> {
  abstract getObservable(): Observable<[HttpResponse<T1>, HttpResponse<T2>]>;
  abstract func(responses: [T1, T2]): void;
  
  getData() {
    this.getObservable().subscribe(
      (http_response) => this.func(http_response.body)
    );
  }
}
```

and possibly overloading to account for the varying amount of observers. But then I run into problems at the line `(http_response) => this.func(http_response.body)` or an unsuccessful work-around I tried `(http_response) => this.func(http_response.map((res) => res.body))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mapped tuple types:

```
type ToObservable<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Observable<T[K]>;
};

type MyObservables = ToObservable<[string, number]>; // [Observable<string>, Observable<number>]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for